# Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration - assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

I'm facing a strange problem that I cannot find any solution on the internet that solves it.

I have a project in .NET 5 which is a working service, some .NET Standard projects and some .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects.

Everything compiles and it runs on debug mode and also if I start the application from the debug folder. However, when I publish the app and try to run the app I get this error from the windows' event viewer

Error
[image]

Is there anyone who faced the same problem and/or knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT #1:

Here are the package references of each project:

.Net 5 project

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.37" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="2.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Standard 2.0 project #1

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Standard 2.0 project #2

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Standard 2.0 project #3

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Standard 2.0 project #4

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Framework 4.7.2 project #1

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Data.SqlClient.4.8.3\lib\net461\System.Data.SqlClient.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.1\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.1\lib\net463\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Framework 4.7.2 project #2

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.Net Framework 4.7.2 project #3

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.1\lib\net463\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

EDIT #2:
I managed to solve the problem ... I downgraded all Microsoft.Extensions.* packages to the version 5.0

Comment: Are you referencing `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` 6.x in one or more of the projects?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @trydis yes, I am. I'm referencing (installed) that package on the .Net 5 and on the .Net Framework 4.7.2 project

Comment: you need to provide info about what assembly version `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll` in the output bin has. And see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is more hairy than the configs you've posted

In one project you have

```xml
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

pay attention to `lib\net461`. net461 is not compatible to .netstandard20

Then you have

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />
```

So which DLL do you actually use? You need to go to your `TargetDir` `bin` find `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll` there and use disassemly or IL DASM to look into the manifest for "Assembly Version". `Version=6.0.0.0` is referred to an assembly version, not file version. Take a note of the assembly version of the actual DLL in the `bin`

NOW! Since you run .net5 you need your DLL to be .netstandard20 to work in .net5 runtime and also be able to work with net472 projects.

And here is part 2 - situation where your one project was built against 1 version of referenced DLL; and another project built against another version of the same DLL. What you need to do is to add [dependency redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This way you tell your assembly to load a different dependency version, not the one listed in the manifest. And it can go up or down in the version.

The answer here is this - research your output. Try redirecting. Potentially you need to fix your references. Use package references instead of `packages.config` to remove pointing to `net461` problem.